# creating a symlink to the python interpreter in a virtualenv messes with the PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

using my system python interpreter (on ubuntu 18.04) i have the following `PYTHONPATH` configured:

```
$ python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.version); print(sys.path)"
3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0]
['', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', 
 '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', 
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', 
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

creating a symlink to the python interpreter does not affect the `PYTHONPATH`:

```
$ cd ~/tmp
$ ln -rs /usr/bin/python3
$ ./python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.version); print(sys.path)"
3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0]
['', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', 
 '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', 
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', 
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

creating a virtualenv and doing the same gives different results, though (i am using `--copies` here, otherwise symlinking with `ln -sr` would link directly back to the system interpreter):

```
$ python3 -m venv virtualenv --copies
$ # making sure python3 is no symlink
$ ls -go virtualenv/bin/python3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 4526456 Jan  8 08:11 virtualenv/bin/python3
$ ./virtualenv/bin/python3  -c "import sys; print(sys.version); print(sys.path)"
3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0]
['', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', 
 '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', 
 '/home/user/tmp/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

up to here everything is as expected. now:

```
$ rm python3
$ ln -sr virtualenv/bin/python3 
$ ./python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.version); print(sys.path)"
3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0]
['', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', 
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', 
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

where `'/home/user/tmp/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages'` (which is basically the whole point of the virtualenv) has gone - instead the original `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` is back.

symlinking to other executables in the virtualenv works:

```
$ ln -sr virtualenv/bin/pip3
$ ./pip3 install mypy         # works!
$ ln -sr virtualenv/bin/mypy
$ ./mypy                      # works!
```

i know that the usual way to work with a virtualenv is to `$ source virtualenv/bin/activate`. but seeing that symlinking works for exectutables in `virtualenv/bin/` i find it disappointing that it does not work for the python interpreter itself.

is there a way i can fix this? (i could of course use a bash script that runs the correct interpreter and passes all the arguments. but i feel like a symlink should be possible...).

---

my current workaround for the time being is a bash script with +/- the contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

HERE=$(dirname $(readlink -f $BASH_SOURCE))
${HERE}/my_symlink_dir/python3 "$@"
```